# JavaScript function synchronous execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
1  var abc;
2    <script>   
3   function fn()
4    {

5      abc = dataResponse.getValue("list");

6      }

7    document.getElementById("id1").innerHtml=abc;
```

here list contains html code received after executing java code now i want to put the value inside div tag but since execution of javascript is asynchronous i am getting abc value undefined and assigned at   line no 7. I need to complete the execution of fn() then value should get assigned to line number 7.And both should be done on page load.And it should work for all the browser i have done using while loop:-
while(i<10)
    {

```
i++;
if(abc)
{
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=abc;
    break;
}else{
    fn();
    }
```

and it works for mozilla and IE but not for chrome and also this is not good practice.How to solve this problem?

This is the code which i am receiving from java

```
<ul class="hello" id="hello" >
       <li><a href="#">India</a>
           <ul >
                <li ><a href="#"> States</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WB</a>
                    <ul >
                        <li ><a href="#">Kolkata</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Silliguri</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kolkata</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Park Street</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">BMW Showroom</a></li>                                       
                                        <li><a href="#">City center</a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">KFC</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">pizzaHut</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: If `fn()` is async, why don't you set the element's html inside it ?

Comment: i tried setting it but still it get assigned first then the fetching of java code completes

Comment: also i am using certain css files for that div portion which does not work if i put that code inside fn() or any other function

Comment: Do you really habe placed that `var` outside of the `<script>`?

Comment: no it is inside script

Answer (score 0):

As your `dataResponse.getValue` function is async, You need to convert the `fn` function to return a promise once the value has been resolved.

```
function fn()
   {
      var defer = $.Deferred();
      abc = dataResponse.getValue("list");
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
          if(abc) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            defer.resolve(abc);
          }
      }, 100);
      return defer.promise();

  }
```

Now,

```
fn().then(function(abc) {
    $("#id1").html(abc);
})
```

Comment: I will repeat the question I asked to OP: why not to set the html to the element *inside* `fn()`? Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Why use `document.getElementById("id1").innerHtml=abc;` when you advocate jQuery. Should use `$('#id1').html('abc');`

Comment: Yes, that makes lot of sense :) I guess may be dataResponse.getValue("list") is asynchronous as OP mentioned like it's getting data from java code ;)

Comment: @click2install Updated it. It should be `$("#id1").html(abc);` where `abc` is a variable not string.

Comment: @mohamedrias Yes my typo ... apologies for that.

Comment: i tried using jquery also same problem @click2install

Comment: yes the response from java code is asynchronous it sends value  after all the javascript is loaded,thats y on setting the variable abc is undefined @mohamedrias

Comment: share code of dataResponse.getValue() function, we can make it to return a promise to make it work :)

Comment: $.deferred(); is not a function error , im using jquery 1.7.2.min.js@mohamedrias

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. It must be $.Deferred() :( @kumar91

Comment: From java i am receiving html code which i am inserting inside div tag and i have included css file for that html code which is displayed inside modal window(through jquery).Now i am getting the value but css doesn't work.Css works as i mentioned above in the code using while loop but does nt work for chrome.What would be the possible reason?

Comment: Regarding CSS, looks strange because css styles apply to dynamically created elements by default. Would be great if you could share the HTML file you're receiving the server.

Comment: i have added the code which i am receiving from server.

Comment: It looks normal. What about your CSS selector for this?

Comment: there is style for all the tags eg:ul,li,a,body which is included in css file and being displayed inside MOdal window created through jquery.Actually i am creating folder hierarchy inside modal window

Comment: I am also using jquery1.8.6 ui.css file

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors with respect to that. May be setup a jsfiddle to emulate. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/o4kr7wbn/

Answer (score 0):

A working JSBin is here using a jQuery `Deferred` object with a `timeout` to simulate the asynchronous call.

http://jsbin.com/lirobuhizu/1/edit